# Where can I find a full and comprehensive knowledge about all nodes?

Tags: node-editor

I am new in 3D and blender. So far I am amazed by its possibilities however there are many areas where It's hard to find any logic behind, especially for beginner like me. One of topic which I would like to know "a bit" deeper are nodes. Can You suggest any good book or other source to gain more knowledge for beginner. Tutorials are very nice everywhere, however they explain nodes partly or only in limited scope.

Comment: There's some good ones about the cycles shader at blenderguru. Google cycles encyclopedia of shaders and you'l get.Let me know if you find one about other aye ;)

Comment: I've already read all before :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good source of all the nodes is [Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/):

- [Compositing nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/index.html#node-types)
- [Cycles material nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/index.html#nodes)
- [Blender Internal material nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/nodes/index.html#material-nodes)

There are also examples of usage, which is most important when it comes to nodes. What matters is the whole network, not just how individual nodes work.

Some other sources:

- the [Cycles shader encyclopedia](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/cycles-shader-encyclopedia/) - just shader nodes examples
- [Chocofur shader examples](http://www.chocofur.com/6-shadersamptextures.html) - full material examples
- [Shader Forge](https://cgcookie.com/course/shader-forge/) - collection of paid and free shader breakdowns
- [PBR by CynicatPro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMpDTk3DTW8&list=PLlH00768JwqG4__RRtKACofTztc0Owys8) - pbr material breakdowns covered also by BlenderGuru [here](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/pbr-shader-tutorial-pt1/) and [here](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/making-realistic-pbr-materials-part-2-metal/).

Some non-bundled addon nodes:

- [Animation nodes](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/index.html)
- [Sverchok nodes](http://sverchok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodes.html)
- [LuxRender nodes](http://www.luxrender.net/wiki/LuxBlend_Node_Editor)

For the complete Blender resources database head over [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender).

Comment: can you add this post to the resources page?

Comment: @cegaton yep, good point.

Comment: @cegaton well, after going through the categories it turns out pretty messy. Can't decide if to put some of these sites under blogs, video tutorials, online courses, addons, documentation etc., as it touches most of them. Ideally I would just restructuralize and organize all the stuff differently..ugh..

Comment: I found this to be very informative http://www.blenderinsight.com/